# Facebook send button without appid

Tags: facebook

Can you use the Facebook send button functionality (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button) without an appid?

The example from the Facebook seems to work without an APP_ID

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.bbc.co.uk" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</body>
```

but didn't want the button to suddenly stop working if this is required!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's needed because the example shown when clicking the "Get Code" button in the link you provided seems to require it.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src =       "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=1530164767244635&version=v2.0";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

I'd recommend using an app_id. Did you try using it without an app_id on your site?

Comment: I want users to be able to share a link to their friends in private messages but don't want to have to create an app just to get an app id.

Comment: Well,  if you tested it and it's working, I'd say go for it.  Couldn't find anything saying that it's strictly required.  I used an app_id once but to make Graph API calls. Since you just want a send button it should be no problem :)

Comment: That was my conclusion but good to get other opinions, thanks :)